# Using ItemizedOverlay and OverlayItem In Android Beta 0.9

Tags: java, android, overlay, android-mapview

Has anyone managed to use `ItemizedOverlays` in Android Beta 0.9? I can't get it to work, but I'm not sure if I've done something wrong or if this functionality isn't yet available.

I've been trying to use the `ItemizedOverlay` and `OverlayItem` classes. Their intended purpose is to simulate map markers (as seen in Google Maps Mashups) but I've had problems getting them to appear on the map.

I can add my own custom overlays using a similar technique, it's just the `ItemizedOverlays` that don't work.

Once I've implemented my own `ItemizedOverlay` (and overridden `createItem`), creating a new instance of my class seems to work (I can extract `OverlayItems` from it) but adding it to a map's `Overlay` list doesn't make it appear as it should.

This is the code I use to add the `ItemizedOverlay` class as an `Overlay` on to my `MapView`.

```
// Add the ItemizedOverlay to the Map
private void addItemizedOverlay() {
  Resources r = getResources();
  MapView mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mymapview);
  List<Overlay> overlays = mapView.getOverlays();

  MyItemizedOverlay markers = new MyItemizedOverlay(r.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
  overlays.add(markers);

  OverlayItem oi = markers.getItem(0);
  markers.setFocus(oi);
  mapView.postInvalidate();
}
```

Where `MyItemizedOverlay` is defined as:

```
public class MyItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
  public MyItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
    super(defaultMarker);
    populate();
  }

  @Override
  protected OverlayItem createItem(int index) {
    Double lat = (index+37.422006)*1E6;
    Double lng = -122.084095*1E6;
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat.intValue(), lng.intValue());

    OverlayItem oi = new OverlayItem(point, "Marker", "Marker Text");
    return oi;
  }

  @Override
  public int size() {
    return 5;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

For the sake of completeness I'll repeat the discussion on Reto's post over at the [Android Groups here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/36fe0648dabfe745#).

It seems that if you set the bounds on your drawable it does the trick:

```
Drawable defaultMarker = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);

// You HAVE to specify the bounds! It seems like the markers are drawn
// through Drawable.draw(Canvas) and therefore must have its bounds set
// before drawing.
defaultMarker.setBounds(0, 0, defaultMarker.getIntrinsicWidth(),
    defaultMarker.getIntrinsicHeight());

MyItemizedOverlay markers = new MyItemizedOverlay(defaultMarker);
overlays.add(markers);
```

By the way, the above is shamelessly ripped from [the demo at MarcelP.info](http://www.marcelp.info/2008/09/01/android-itemizedoverlay-demo/). Also, here is a [good howto](http://androidguys.com/?p=1413).

Comment: is it just me or your last like is empty ?

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
Drawable defaultMarker = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);

defaultMarker.setBounds(0, 0, defaultMarker.getIntrinsicWidth(),
    defaultMarker.getIntrinsicHeight());

MyItemizedOverlay markers = new MyItemizedOverlay(defaultMarker);
overlays.add(markers);
```